# Finding the closest match to a string

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, match

I'm querying users from an active directory source and pulling their names, from their I'm trying to pull the closest match via given input:

```
from pyad import adquery
import difflib


data = []
q = adquery.ADQuery()
q.execute_query(
    base_dn="some info"

)

data_given = raw_input("Enter user(last,first): ")

for row in q.get_results():
    item = row["distinguishedName"]
    user = ''.join(item.split(",")[0:2:])
    new_user = user.replace("\\", ",").replace("CN=", "")
    print new_user
    if new_user == data_given:
        data = [new_user]
    else:
        data = difflib.get_close_matches(data_given, new_user, n=10, cutoff=1.0)


if not data:
    print "No user was found with the criteria given."
else:
    print data
```

However, the users I'm pulling will end up looking like this:

```
Kadiyala, Chndr
Doulas, Jh P.
Perkins, Thomas - OSM-OCO CTR
Lattsw, Tamka M - OAM OCO
```

And the `difflib` will not pull the closest match.

For example, lets say the user inputs "Perkins, Thomas":

```
Enter user(last,first): Perkins, Thomas
No user was found with the criteria given.
```

Is there a way I can get `difflib` to pull a match based on how many characters match in the given criteria? I've searched the docs, and couldn't seem to find anything on changing the match criteria for `difflib`.

Comment: `possibilities` is supposed to be a list of strings while your `new_user` is a single string. Also, wouldn't you collect all names from the query in one list and _then_ use `get_close_matches()` on all of them at once?

Answer (score 0):

This should be doable if you convert the returned data from

```
q.get_results()
```

into a list of names, like

```
users_list = ['Kadiyala, Chndr', 'Doulas, Jh', ...]
```

where the names are all stripped of extra data, such as `Perkins, Thomas - OSM-OCO CTR` -> `Perkins, Thomas`. This can be done with regex (see https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html). Try

```
valid_users = []
for name in users_list:
     valid_users.append(re.match('\\w+(,)\\s{1}\\w+', name).group(0))
```

Then you can run

```
data = difflib.get_close_matches(data_given, valid_users, n=10, cutoff=1.0)
```

to get the first at most 10 users who have exactly the name specified.

**However**, if your user's names are unique, `n=10` would be overridden by `cutoff=1.0` in the difflib call, since there would be only 1 exact matching name in `valid_users`.